# ngx-translate not working after i add HttpInterceptor

Tags: angular6, angular-http-interceptors, angular-pipe, angular-i18n

like the title says , everything was working fine until i add HttpInterceptor to my code , the problem is i have 2 ways to translate my fields one is still working fine and the second is not like shown bellow

```
 <dx-button 
    (click)="logIn()" 
    type="default" id="buttonLogIn"
    text="{{ 'LoginPage.Login'|translate }}">
</dx-button>
<span id="containerStayConnected"><input type="checkbox" id="stayConnected" [(ngModel)]="stayConnected" /><label for="stayConnected" translate>LoginPage.StayConnected</label></span>
<a id="forgetPassword" translate (click)="isPopupForgotPasswordVisible = !isPopupForgotPasswordVisible">LoginPage.ForgotPassword</a><br><br><br>
```

the translate inside the balise  is working while the translate that using pipe in dxButton is not working 
this is my interceptor service

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor(public auth: AuthService) {}

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const userId = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${userId}`
        }
    });
    return next.handle(request);
}
```

}
does anyone have any idea about why after i add the httpInterceptor the translate that using Pipe stop working .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved the issue for this by removing `public auth: AuthService` from the constructor.
I think what creates the issue here is HttpInterceptor and AuthService both injects HttpClient.
If anyone interessted to check more informations about similars issues just check here 
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18224

Comment: yup there were cyclic dependencies, it is working after removing cyclic dependencies

Comment: I have the same issue, i went through the link u mentioned, but it's still not working for me. I am using HttpClient only. I don't have any auth services except a simple interceptor. I added my interceptor code here https://codepen.io/rajeshwarpatlolla/pen/rNeLOQj and i also added translation loader code in the same file at the bottom. Please help me fix this issue.